# Javascript / Jquery currency format onChange & percent calc

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal-point, currency-formatting

It might be sleep deprivation but having a challenging time trying to format a function to:

- Field 2 = Field 1 * 1.15 return a dollar amount
- Field 3 = user defined whole percent
- Field 4 = Field 3 * Field 2 return a dollar amount

I've attempted to add the jquery currency format, but obviously it is not linking correctly.  I'd appreciate any guidance of where I am going wrong - I have researched this and not comprehending some of the answers. Thanks in advance your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.css" />

   <style>

.quote {width:600px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold;}
.data {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top:20px; padding-left:40px;}
.data1 {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top:20px; padding-left:40px; font-weight:bold}
.input {width:10px;}
.label1 {padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:20px; }
.label2 {padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:20px;}
.field {padding-left:75px;}


   </style>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js">
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.formatCurrency.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

       function compute() {
              var a = $('#a').val(); //field1

              var total = a * 1.15; //field2
              $('#total').val(total); //field1 * 1.15 = field2
              var c = $('#c').val(); //field3 percent defined
              var calc = (c /10) * total;  
               $('#calc').val(calc); //calc field4
                var calc2 = (calc + total);  
               $('#calc2').val(calc2); //calc field5 (field2 + field3)
               var calc3 = (total * .20);  
               $('#calc3').val(calc3); //calc field6 (field2 x 20%)
               var calc4 = (total * .80);  
               $('#calc4').val(calc4); //calc field7 (field2 x 80%)
               var d = $('#d').val(); //field8 percent defined
               var calc5 = (d /10) * total;  
               $('#calc5').val(calc5); //calc field9
               var calc6 = (a * 1);  
               $('#calc6').val(calc6); //calc field10
               var calc7 = (calc3 - calc4);  
               $('#calc7').val(calc7); //calc field11
               var calc8 = (a * 1);  
               $('#calc8').val(calc8); //calc field12
               var calc9 = (a - calc5);  
               $('#calc9').val(calc9); //calc field13      
            }

            $('#a, #c, #calc, #calc2, #calc3, #calc4, #calc5, #d, #calc6, #calc7, #calc8, #calc9, #input').change(compute)


         $('#input').currency();


     });
    </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="irr">
          <div data-role="header">

          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div class="quote">
              <label for="a">Field 1</label>
              <input width:"10px" type="number" name="a" id="a" value=""  /> </div>
              <div class="data1">
               <br>
          <label for="total"> = Field 2</label>
          <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value=""  />   </div>
          <div class="data">
         <label for="c">- Field 3 </label>
          <input type="number" name="c" id="c" maxlength="2" value=""  />%

         Field 4 (<label for="calc"> </label>
          <input type="number" name="calc" id="calc" value=""  />)</div>
            <div class="data1">      
                 <label for="calc2">= Field 5</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc2" id="calc2" value=""  /></div>
       <div class="data">    
      <label for="calc3">- Field 6 (20%)</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc3" id="calc3" value=""  /></div>
          <div class="data1">    
                    <label for="calc4">= Field 7</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc4" id="calc4" value=""  /></div>
        <div class="data">    
          <label for="d">- Field 8</label>
          <input type="number" name="d" id="d"maxlength="2" value=""  />

                        <label for="calc5"></label>
         Field 9 (<input type="number" name="calc5" id="calc5" value=""  />)</div>
 <div class="data1">  
        <label for="calc6">= Field 10</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc6" id="calc6" value=""  />

          <label for="calc7">Field 11</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc7" id="calc7" value=""  /></div>
          <div class="data1">  
          <label for="calc8">Field 12 on</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc8" id="calc8" value=""  />

          <label for="calc9">Field 13</label>
          <input type="number" name="calc9" id="calc9" value=""  /></div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: why are you using `jquery.mobile-1.0b1` with jQuery 1.9?

Comment: To get the percent difined you need to /100, not by 10. 100 * 1 = 100%, 100*0.8 = 80%, 80/10 = 8, 80/100 = 0.8

Comment: @Mathletics it's for style - nothing else.  I don't need it, just part of my test.

Comment: @Guerra - THANK YOU that was helpful. I swear at some point I tested that.  I'm having one of those days where I just need to walk away from the screen.